# how to use CURL to post a message like field=value , i used -d and -f but it all failed

Tags: python, flask, curl

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    msg = request.form['msg']
    return msg
```

```
curl -X POST -d 'msg = test' 127.0.0.1:5000/test
curl -X POST -F 'msg = test' 127.0.0.1:5000/test
The method is not allowed for the requested URL
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2022 03:18:18] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 405
```

Comment: You may need to add an http.   http://127.0.0.1:5000/test

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `POST` request with `curl`, but you have only defined your route for a `GET` request. You need to write:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    msg = request.form['msg']
    return msg
```

And then use the `-F` argument to curl:

```
curl -F msg=test localhost:5000/test
```

Answer (score 0):

The error to lookout for is

> `The method is not allowed for the requested URL`

You may require both `POST` and `GET` here. Not mentioning `methods` parameter in `@app.route()` defaults it to `GET` only. So, you would need to add that parameter to enable serving `POST` requests.

So, your first line should be as

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

and your problem should be resolved.